# Enable kernel debugging option in stock kernel

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel

Could I modify a stock kernel(downloaded Ubuntu image) configuration that I have not been compiled for kernel debugging purposes or I need to compile a new kernel with the kernel debugging option enabled?

Comment: What do you mean kernel debugging option  enabled. there are numerous options available for debugging it's not just one. what are you missing ?

Comment: My current Ubuntu kernel is compiled with no CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO option enabled. I want to to recompile my Ubuntu kernel within the same machine. Is that possible? How? @stdcall